# html5 php video upload and display - how to add comments to specific upload

Tags: php, mysql, html, video, comments

I am building a website in which users can upload videos, and comment on videos that have been uploaded.  I have a working php function that uploads the video, but now I would like to include a link below the video that references that particular video to add comments.

This is my php code to display the video:

```
    <?php


    $sql="SELECT * FROM video";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $rows=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);



    foreach ($rows as $row) {

    ?>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="service">
                        <video id="<?= $row["v_id"] ?>" width="350" height="315" controls="controls">
                        <source src="uploads/<?= $row["video_name"] ?>" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                        </video>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comments">View/Add Comments</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>

    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

And the 'View/Add Comments' links to the following modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="comments" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="text-center">
            <div class="modal-content modal-popup2">
                <h3 class="grey">Comments</h3>
                <?php

                $sql="SELECT * FROM comments";
                $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                $rows=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);



                foreach ($rows as $row) {

                ?>

                <div class="bold black">
                <?php echo $row["author"] ?> says:
                <p>
                <?php echo $row["comment"] ?>
                </p>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>

                <h3 class="grey">Write a comment</h3>
                <form method="post" action="comments.php">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input id="author" name="author" type="text" class="form-control form-grey" placeholder="Enter name">
                    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control form-grey" placeholder="Enter comment" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This displays the comments from the database and allows the users to add their own comment. However this is generic for all videos and is not specific to the individual v_id. I don't know where to start with this, am very new to php!

I know I'll need to add to my comments database table with the v_id, and update the comments.php file with the v_id of the comment, so any suggestions on getting started would be great!

Let me know if you have any more questions or need to see anymore of the code!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$sql="SELECT * FROM comments";` must be extended to limit the query to a specific v_id. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html about the *WHERE* argument to SELECT.

Notice that any value to a SQL query **SHOULD** be passed using a placeholder. Inserting values directly into the query is highly risky because it usually causes SQL injection vulnerabilities*. Ask Google about *SQL injection* for more information.

Your *mysqli_query* might not work with placeholders. See http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php for more details on this.

PS: * An experienced developer could avoid this even with values within the query, but the simple safe solution is: Always(!) use placeholders.